# Will ticking the "Install third-party software" box install non open-source software?

Tags: boot

I am trying switch to ubuntu and only want to use open source software. Should I tick "Install third party software" or should I install what I need manually?

Comment: You can certainly configure Ubuntu to have only free software, but this may be helpful. https://www.gnu.org/distros/free-distros.html

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to stick to running *only* open source software, then you will likely want to stay away from ticking the box. Not all third-party software is closed source, but not checking the box will give you the opportunity to first research the packages you need/want, then install them manually later.